# Android Application Permissions Logging

Tags: android, logging, user-controls, android-permissions, user-permissions

i have a question related to Android app run time permissions.

Is it preferrable/allowed practice for developers to save users' permission preferences i.e. each user has allowed/denied any permission, on our remote server database?
Offcourse we are asking run time permission for every feature we want to use, but is it preferrable that we log on server that if user has allowed for any permission or not, please let know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android framework has restricted the developers to ask only those permissions which are necessary to implement a specific feature and that too if there's no other way to implement the feature without that specific permission. In your case, it seems like you have already taken care of the permissions and just want to hold the result of the asked permissions.
So the answer is YES, You can save this data and it's even considered good practice for handling permissions. Here's the reference from the official android documentation.

**Greater flexibility in granting permissions**

Users can deny access to individual permissions at the time they’re requested and in settings, but they may still be surprised when functionality is broken as a result. It’s a good idea to monitor how many users are denying permissions (e.g. using Google Analytics) so that you can either refactor your app to avoid depending on that permission or provide a better explanation of why you need the permission for your app to work properly. You should also make sure that your app handles exceptions when users deny permission requests or toggle off permissions in settings.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes

Comment: good answer, but my assumption is, permissions allow/deny is user's personal preference and we should not have any control or any history of it. Here we are logging each and every run time permissions response of user.